# A client is accessing our angular web app in Citrix and occasionally freezes for multiples of 5 minutes

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, citrix

This is a bit of a vague question I'm afraid, but I thought I'd ask just in case anyone had any idea.

We have a cloud based angular web app with a .Net web api.

The big caveat here is that I haven't used Citrix for almost 20 years and don't really know anything about it these days.

99.999% of our users have no problems, some of them are even using Citrix to deliver the app through a browser without any issues.

One organisation is having intermittent issues where the app will freeze on API requests for multiples of almost exactly five minutes (sometimes 5, sometimes 10). It's almost as if it's queuing up requests and then releasing them after 5 or 10 minutes.

Given I know nothing about Citrix, Google has come up blank as well and the NFP organisation did not set up their own Citrix environment so have no expert to talk to, can anyone provide any ideas or insight as to where we should start looking for a solution.

Thanks,
R.

Comment: It's been a couple of years since I have worked with Citrix (XenApp 6.5ish) - I'm going to say the issue is with their configuration, or the browser, browser version, etc.. they're publishing the app through. We used to have all sorts of issues publishing apps through Chrome (high resource utilization) and 90% of the time switching to Firefox would clear up a ton of issues. Is the browser they're using to publish the app fully patched? Maybe have them update the published browser or test out a different browser.

Comment: Yes, their Chrome is fully patched. Further investigation seems to show the 5 min timeout is coming from Chrome, so it calls our API, has no response back, then cancels can calls again.
Our API doesn't receive anything at that point.

Comment: Just from my experience with Citrix - I highly doubt the issue is on your end. Have them publish Firefox as a test - I bet that fixes it. Good luck with this!